# Pass generic to the extension method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, parameters, extension-methods

I'm trying to make a generic method to execute a query where I can pass stored proc name and the parameters if any .

After executing the query the results are stored in a DataTable
which has to be converted to a List.

> DataTableToList()

is an extension method which will do the same.

*Only relevant code shown*

**Caller**

```
        var results=  dh.ExecuteDataSet<EmployeeModel>("USP_GetEmployeeByID", new Dictionary<string, IConvertible>()
        {
                 {"@ID", 1000}
             });
```

**DAL code**

```
public IEnumerable<T>  ExecuteDataSet<T>(string storedProcName, IDictionary<string, IConvertible> parameters = null)
            {                            
                    var result = db.ExecuteDataSet(q);

                    DataTable dtResult = result.Tables[0];

                    var t = dtResult.DataTableToList<T>();  //Compile time error: The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 

                        return t;

                }
```

**Extension method**

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
        {
            try
            {
                List<T> list = new List<T>();

                foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
                {
                    T obj = new T();

                    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                            propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    list.Add(obj);
                }

                return list;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the extension method call gives the compile time error

> ```
> The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter compile time error.
> ```

So what changes are to be made to the extension method so that it accepts a generic as an argument?

Comment: `DataTableToList` has generic constraint `T:class` but the other extension method doesn't have that constraint. That's why you are seeing this error. You need to apply the same constraint there too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This procedure:

```
public IEnumerable<T>  ExecuteDataSet<T>(
    string storedProcName,
    IDictionary<string, IConvertible> parameters = null)
```

Also needs the type parameters.

```
where T : class, new()
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `where T : class` to your DAL method.
The compiler needs to know that your `T` in the DAL method can satisfy the type constraints of the extension method